# How can I add some bad words as whitelist on JavaScript

Tags: javascript, filter, discord, bots, chat

*The blacklisted words are bad words but the words that appear on whitelisted are really clean words but the bot detects them too as a bad word. How can I solve this?*

Thanks in advance.

```
const Discord = require('discord.js');
const client = new Discord.Client();
client.once('ready', () => {
  console.log('Bot is online!');
});
const prefix = '&';
client.on('message', message => {
  let blacklisted = ['bad words'];
  let whitelisted = ['clean words'];
  let foundInText = false;
  for (var i in blacklisted) {
    
    if(message.content.toLowerCase().includes(blacklisted[i].toLowerCase())) foundInText = true;
  }
    if(foundInText){
      message.delete();
      const embed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
      .setTitle('W A R N')
      .setDescription(message.author.toString() + ' we don't allow to write this here.')
      .setThumbnail('logo link')
      .setAuthor(client.user.username)
      .setColor('RANDOM')
      .addFields(
        {name: 'Explain' , value: 'explainv2.' + '\n' + 'The bad word: ' + '**' + message.toString() + '**'},
        )
        message.channel.send(embed)
          .then(message => message.delete({ timeout: 15000}))
    }
});

client.login('discord bot id');
```

Comment: Where do you use the whitelist? Also, you have an early closed quite in `don't`

Comment: I use it for a discord bot. also I gotta change it. removeWords is whitelist

Comment: why is there a need for a whitelist? Surely every word that is not blacklisted is therefore whitelisted?